# How to connect kafka producer and consumer to a machine that is running kafka and zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a ubuntu machine that is having kafka and zookeepr installed in it, I am using spring boot for making the consumer and producer, locally the process works, however, when the deploy the producer and consumer jar to another machine it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Kafka defaults to only listen locally.

You need to set these in Kafka's `server.properties`

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<external-ip>:9092
```

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Then, obviously, don't use `localhost:9092` in your remote client code.

You should never need Zookeeper connection details. Besides, as of Kafka 3.3.1, Zookeeper isn't required at all.

Comment: Actually I did it but didnt use systemctl stop kafka command , later I did it is working now